# tizen git repository not found, why?

Tags: git, clone, tizen

I went to the tizen docs. They said type this in to cl;one repository :
$ git clone https://git.tizen.org/cgit/platform/framework/web/chromium-efl.git

So I did, but then this happend:
Cloning into 'chromium-efl'...
fatal: repository 'https://git.tizen.org/cgit/platform/framework/web/chromium-efl.git/' not found

why is this happening, becuse I can view the repository online, and the command I entered was the one on the documentation, so it should be correct

Comment: Hello, would you let me know the link of guide web page?

Answer (score 1):

The repository URL on the [project index](https://git.tizen.org/cgit/platform/framework/web/chromium-efl/) is: `https://git.tizen.org/cgit/platform/framework/web/chromium-efl` or
`git://git.tizen.org/platform/framework/web/chromium-efl`.

```
git clone git://git.tizen.org/platform/framework/web/chromium-efl
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried it out and it worked properly